# Gradle not able to install properly

Tags: classpath, gradle

I am trying to install the gradle 1.3 on window 7 machine and did the following steps

1.Downloaded the gradle-1.3.all.zip from http://www.gradle.org/ url

2.Extracted it to **F:\localRepository\gradle-1.3**

3.Set the environment variables

**GRADLE_HOME=F:\localRepository\gradle-1.3**

**GRADLE_OPTS=F:\localRepository\gradle-1.3\bin**

**PATH = F:\localRepository\gradle-1.3\bin;F:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin**

**JAVA_HOME=F:\jdk1.7.0_21**

**JAVA_OPTS=F:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin**

4.RUN gradle in CMD

5.getting

**"Could not find or load main class F:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin"**

Can anyone suggest me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Those JAVA_OPTS look suspicious to me. What are you trying to achieve by setting them to that?

If you look at gradle.bat (in F:\localRepository\gradle-1.3\bin) you'll see this line which actually launches Java to run Gradle:

"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

So as far as Java's concerned, your %JAVA_OPTS% looks like the name of the main class. Everything after that just gets parsed as parameters.

JAVA_OPTS is for the parameters you want to pass to the JVM.

Your GRADLE_OPTS also looks a bit unusual.

Comment: Thanks!! I have removed the JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS from the system variables and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

about the JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS I'm citing from Gradle documentation:

> JVM OPTIONS
>   JVM options for running Gradle can be set via environment variables. You can use GRADLE_OPTS >or JAVA_OPTS. Those variables can be used together. JAVA_OPTS is by convention an environment >variable shared by many Java applications. A typical use case would be to set the HTTP proxy >in JAVA_OPTS and the memory options in GRADLE_OPTS. Those variables can also be set at the >beginning of the gradle or gradlew script.
>
> http://www.gradle.org/installation

But in general it's not suitable placeholder for bin folder. You better define your Path variable as:

```
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;
```

and remove or redefine your JAVA_OPTS or GRADLE_OPTS variables.

Comment: thanks for reply its working now after removing the JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS variables.